# Swift/iOS SDK: Generic Function with Class Type/Name Closure/Block Issue

Tags: ios, swift, generics, closures

I'm trying to write a generic class, that takes a custom class name and creates an instance of that class name. 
Before and after creation I do some generic stuff that applies to all classes. 
I want to add some parameters to the instance that are class specific. That's why I added a closure that gets called after the instance was created with the instance object itself as a parameter of the closure. The closure is optional.
Interestingly calling the function without the closure works just fine, if I add the closure I get the following compiler error:

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name

This compiler error applies for the first parameter, which makes no sense, since calling the function just with the first parameter works fine...

I have added my simple example for Playground use:

```
class Base {
    var test1: Int = 0
}

class A: Base {
    var test2: Int = 0
}

class B: Base {
    var test3: Int = 0
}

func create<T: Base>(aClass: T.Type, addParameter:((T) -> Void)? = nil) {
    println("Do generic stuff before object is created")

    var object = aClass()

    // Add custom class specific parameters to object
    if let l_addParameter = addParameter {
        l_addParameter(object)
    }

    println("Do generic stuff after object was created")
}

create(A)
create(B)
create(B, addParameter: { (b: B) -> Void in
    b.test3 = 1000
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to pass a `Type` is `ClassName.self`, e.g.

```
create(A.self)
create(B.self, addParameter: { (b: B) -> Void in
    b.test3 = 1000
})
```

(and I cannot tell you why omitting `.self` works if the function 
is called without additional arguments).

With this correction, your code *compiles* without errors, but does
not work. As noticed in [Swift Generic Factory: Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500438/swift-generic-factory-bug),
you have to add an required `init` method to your base class,

```
class Base {
    required init() { } // ***
    var test1: Int = 0
}
```

otherwise

```
var object = aClass()
```

will always create an object of the base class and not of the actual
type what was passed as an argument (and therefore `b.test3 = 1000`
in the closure will abort with an exception).